# How to send logs from Log4J to Fluentd editind lo4j.properties

Tags: log4j, fluentd, treasure-data

I'm have a fluentd setup currently using TCP as a source to receive some logs, it's working fine. Now I need to set up another application that uses Log4J, but i musnt change the source code, only the config files. How can I setup log4j.properties (or other files) to send logs to fluentd(running in another machine, but in the same network)?
Right now I have:

I was testing both a appender made to fluentd and the socket one, to send using TCP, but it's not working.

```
#TEST#
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, BLAH  
# to connect to the remote server 
log4j.appender.BLAH=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender  
# set set that layout to be SimpleLayout 
log4j.appender.BLAH.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout  
#log4j.appender.BLAH.File= admin.log  
log4j.appender.BLAH.Port= 21001 
log4j.appender.BLAH.RemoteHost=tcp://192.168.14.130

log4j.rootLogger=WARN, fluentd
log4j.appender.fluentd=com.twimba.fluentd4log4j.FluentdAppender.java
log4j.appender.fluentd.host="192.168.14.130"
log4j.appender.fluentd.port=21003
log4j.appender.fluentd.tag="log4j"
```

Currently my fluentd instance is not receiving anything.
I wish it's were showing the logs.

Comment: could you please share why the logs from log4j would not be sent? If a log-driver is configured in the application container, would it not pick the log4j logs?

Answer (score 3):

There are some log4j appenders for Fluentd.

- https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-java/issues/54
- https://github.com/ipros-team/fluent-appender
- https://github.com/tuxetuxe/fluentd4log4j

Comment: I've seen these solutions, but because of the lack of documentation I could not figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fluentd-log4j-appender specified in https://github.com/technologize/fluency-log4j-appender